# Можно ли разбить dataframe на несколько?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть dataframe типа ['time','data']

```
base_df:
time               data
1970-1-1 12:55:50  data1
1970-1-1 12:55:52  data2
2023-6-3 12:35:50  data3
2023-6-3 12:55:50  data4
1970-1-1 12:12:12  data5
1970-1-1 12:12:13  data6
2023-6-3 16:45:50  data7
2023-6-3 16:46:50  data8
...
```

Такой датафрейм надо разбить каждый раз когда время сбрасывается
должны получится такие датафреймы

```
df1:
time               data
1970-1-1 12:55:50  data1
1970-1-1 12:55:52  data2
2023-6-3 12:35:50  data3
2023-6-3 12:55:50  data4
df2:
time               data
1970-1-1 12:12:12  data5
1970-1-1 12:12:13  data6
2023-6-3 16:45:50  data7
2023-6-3 16:46:50  data8
...
dfN:
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать простой группировкой по возрастающему значению:

```
grp = base_df.groupby((base_df["time"]<base_df["time"].shift()).cumsum())
res = [grp.get_group(x) for x in grp.groups]
```

теперь в res у вас список датафреймов, в каждом из которых время идёт по возрастающей.